# PayPal Checkout Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, frontend, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to set up a working paypal button for a personal e-commerce web app.

My sandbox text app works perfect in taking payments/non-payments and returns but when i change my client-id to the live version it gives me an error.

It says the card cannot be used.

I am also based in Ireland, on the off chance location is a problem.

My code is as followed.

My client id is followed up with '...&currency=EUR'

I should point out this is when clicking the pay with credit/debit card option. I have not tested payment from a Paypal account yet.

It says please use another card or billing address error.

```js
useEffect(() => {

  window.paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
      return actions.order.create({
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
        purchase_units: [{
          description: 'Door to Door',
          amount: {
            currency_code: 'EUR',
            value: 0.01
          }
        }]
      })
    },
    onApprove: async(data, actions) => {
      const order = await actions.order.capture();
      setPaidFor(true);
      sendEmail();
      console.log(order)

    },
    onError: (err) => {

      setPaidError(true);

    }
  }).render(paypal.current)
}, [])
```

Comment: Perhaps due to Brexit ? ;)

Comment: I would search my error message after removing application specific content. It is always a good idea to include the exact error message in an SO question - `It says the card cannot be used.` is not likely the exact error you get?

Comment: i mean about the paypal smart button it says in red 'card cannot be used'

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that card was declined for the purposes of that payment in live and can't be used. Not an integration problem.

This is not unusual if paying a ridiculously low amount like $0.01 or doing live test payments to your own account, which are not permitted. Use the sandbox environment for your own testing.

Comment: one payment has gone through using a revolut card, when i use an irish bank card or revolut card it usually says " card cannot be used" in red over  the paypal smart button